# Best way to handle a 404 in a file download HTTP handler?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, httphandler

I've got a grid which provides some links for users to download files. Files are stored outside of the application, the path references are read from the database and a HTTP handler (*.ashx) is used to serve each requested file. It is, however, possible that there could be a database entry pointing to a non existent file. I catch the `FileNotFoundException`, but I'm not sure what would be the best method to inform the user of the missing file (so that they can contact support).

First idea is to set a standard 404 code on the response, and that's what I'm doing now.

A more helpful way would be to display a notification (jQuery) about a missing file, but the file download is not done in AJAX, so this would involve a two step process - a client side onclick handler calls a web service method to check if the file exists, if not, then I cancel the click (return false) and display a friendly message to the user. If the file exists however, I proceed with the normal execution. But this adds yet another server call.

Have you dealt with a similar problem? How did you solve it?

Some clarifications - the application is built in ASP.NET 2.0 and uses jQuery to call the web service methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pawel, it seems you've answered your question already...

> ...(so that they can contact
>   support)...

By stating the above I would suggest you create a custom 404 page which notifies the user of the file not existing on disk and provide them information on how to get in contact with the support office.

I've created a HTTP Handler for handling files and if a file does not exist on disk then I return a 404 response. I've setup IIS to display a custom page if a 404 reponse has been thrown.. (and I do the same for error 500).

Hope this helps and good luck with finding the solution that fits your needs!

Comment: But then I can't differentiate between a missing file situation and that when a whole page is missing. I could provide some more elaborate explanation on the 404 page, such as "if you were trying to download a file contact support, if you were trying to access a page it can't be found", etc.)...

Comment: Well you could implement in your HTTP handler to redirect to a file not found specific 404 page, otherwise return a 'normal' 404?

Comment: Doh! Of course the redirect works! I was relying on the Framework to redirect to the 404 page by passing a status code, instead of doing a simple Response.Redirect(). So obvious... Thanks!